# dependent binary variables in Pyomo

Tags: python, variables, dependencies, constraints, pyomo

I'm having problems formulating a constraint in Pyomo where I want to determine a dependency between two variables.
In my model I have 3 binary variables in total:

```
model.x = pyo.Var(model.M, domain=pyo.Binary)
model.y = pyo.Var(model.M, domain=pyo.Binary)
model.z = pyo.Var(model.M, domain=pyo.Binary)
```

My objective function with the parameter `model.l` would be:

```
obj_expr = sum(model.l[i] * model.x[i] + model.l[i] * model.y[i] for i in model.M)
model.obj = pyo.Objective(sense=pyo.maximize, expr=obj_expr)
```

I would like `model.z` to be the opposite of `model.x`, so that a 1 in model.x[i] would be a 0 in model.z[i].

I tried to do this with the following constraint:

```
    def dependent_var_con(model, i):
        lhs = model.z[i]
        rhs = model.x[i]
        return lhs != rhs 
    model.con = pyo.Constraint(model.M, expr=dependent_var_con)
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work and I'm getting the following error:

*Cannot convert non-constant Pyomo expression (z[0]  ==  x[0]) to bool.
This error is usually caused by using a Var, unit, or mutable Param in a
Boolean context such as an "if" statement, or when checking container
membership or equality.*

Does anyone have an idea how to deal with this issue?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the "not equal" logical operator in a linear program.  All you get are inequalities and equal.  :)

However, if you just want to invert a binary variable, it is pretty straightforward with a little algebra.  In your case:

```
z[i] == 1 - x[i]
```

pop that in a constraint for all `i`